# что делать, если задано неверное значение и переменная должна остаться без изменений java

Tags: java, if, variable

переменная должна остаться без изменений, если задано неверное значение

```
public void setFirstName(String firstNameIn)
    {
        if (firstNameIn != null)
        {
            firstName = firstNameIn;
        }
        else 
        {
            firstName = firstNameIn;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Ну наверное, поменять условие и убрать else, нет?

Comment: Что подразумевается под неверным значением? Значение null? или пустая строка? или длинной больше/меньше определенной? или еще что-то?

Answer (score 1):

Неверное значение аргумента? Если я правильно понял задание то ответ может быть таким.

```
public void setFirstName(String firstNameIn)
    {
        if (firstNameIn != null)
        {
            firstName = firstNameIn;
        }
        else 
        {
            firstName = firstName;
        }
    }
```

Comment: А какой толк от выражения
"else 
        {
            firstName = firstName;
        }"?
этот же код ничего не делает, его можно смело удалить. И этот метод считает неверным значением только null, а по условиям не понятно, что именно является верным, а что нет.

Comment: Согласен что можно и удалить спокойно. Оставил просто для наглядности что переменная останется такой как есть. Тем более не знаю рамки задания и можно ли убрать else.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял задание, то вам нужно не выполнять ф-ю дальше, если в качестве аргумента передано неверное значение. Предложу следующие решения(с выбросом исключения и без него):

```
public void f1(/*аргументы ф-ции*/) throws IllegalArgumentException{
    if(/*условие того, что некий аргумент не подходит*/) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    //ваши действия, если аргумент подходит
}

public void f2(/*аргументы ф-ции*/){
    if(/*условие того, что некий аргумент не подходит*/) {
        return;
    }
    //ваши действия, если аргумент подходит
}
```